# Prevent crashes when subclassing PFUser

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

We have an App in production and received some EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crashes, when accessing a new variable inside User (a subclass of PFUser).

```
class User : PFUser {

@NSManaged var name: String!
@NSManaged var age: Int
...

var newVariable: Int = 0
}
```

Since Parse caches PFUser, the cached version of currentUser (from the previous version) does not contain newVariable. After calling .fetch() on User.currentUser() the App stops crashing.

Here's the crash log:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libGSFontCache.dylib       0x2000000000000 (Missing)
1  APP                        0x1001d8b54 AvatarImageView.(updateUI in _0CCBFAE82915B0F511DDDA83596201DC)() -> () (AvatarImageView.swift:119)
2  APP                        0x1001d9a48 specialized AvatarImageView.user.setter (AvatarImageView.swift:37)
3  APP                        0x1001d783c AvatarImageView.user.setter (AvatarImageView.swift)
4  APP                        0x1001dbea4 ProfileHeaderView.(initView in _8556F2EAEF99C54ED4DABB5A0C260DAE)() -> () (ProfileHeaderView.swift:98)
5  APP                        0x1001db7f4 ProfileHeaderView.init(type : ProfileHeaderView.ViewType, user : User, buddy : Buddy?) -> ProfileHeaderView (ProfileHeaderView.swift:66)
6  APP                        0x10018c49c ProfileViewController.initView() -> () (ProfileViewController.swift:123)
7  APP                        0x1000d9258 BaseViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (BaseViewController.swift:52)
8  APP                        0x10018bd64 ProfileViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (ProfileViewController.swift:79)
9  APP                        0x10018bf88 @objc ProfileViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (ProfileViewController.swift)
10 UIKit                      0x1862ec0c0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
11 UIKit                      0x1863abda8 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
12 UIKit                      0x1863abc80 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
13 UIKit                      0x1863aaec8 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 144
14 UIKit                      0x1863aaa6c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
15 UIKit                      0x1863aa694 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60    
16 UIKit                      0x1863aa5fc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
17 UIKit                      0x1862e7778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
18 QuartzCore                 0x183cf6b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
19 QuartzCore                 0x183cf1738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
20 QuartzCore                 0x183cf15f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
21 QuartzCore                 0x183cf0c94 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
22 QuartzCore                 0x183cf09dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
23 QuartzCore                 0x183cea0cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
24 CoreFoundation             0x1815b0588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
25 CoreFoundation             0x1815ae32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
26 CoreFoundation             0x1814dd6a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
27 UIKit                      0x18635a580 -[UIApplication _run] + 460 
28 UIKit                      0x186354d90 UIApplicationMain + 204 
29 APP                        0x1000c3dfc main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
30 libdispatch.dylib          0x18107e8b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to the `newVariable`. A new `User` instance will find the value equal to `0` and won't crash

Comment: This line is reposnible for the crash: let variable = FriendLevel(rawValue: user?.newVariable ?? 0). user?.name is used before without any issue.

Comment: I'm just saying that from the stack trace, doesn't seem the problem. It seems something related to a font that you are trying to load in `AvatarImageView`, in the `updateUI` method